# recaptcha issue on ios device

Tags: ios, recaptcha, google-api-client

We have added reCaptcha in an html page. On successful verification of reCaptcha, the page automatically scrolls down while the expected behavior is that page will remain as it is.
Some things to note:
1. Page is included in an iframe on another page
2. This only happens when the page is being used on iPhone on any browser.

We have tried changing location.hash so that page is scrolled to the specified anchor as a workaround. Also tried using scrollTo and focus functions. This was done in callback of the reCaptcha verification. These workarounds did not work (maybe because the page is included in an iframe).